# How can I display the newly added item on top of the previous item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I display the newly added item on top of the previous item?

```
<div className="App">
      <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
      <form ref="myForm" className="myForm">
        <input type="text" ref="input" placeholder="your name" className="formField" />
        <button onClick={(e)=>this.fSubmit(e)} className="myButton">submit </button>
      </form>
      <pre>
      {datas.map((data, i) =>
          <li reverse key={i} className="myList">
            {data.input}
            <button onClick={()=>this.fRemove(i)} className="myListButton">remove </button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.fEdit(i)} className="myListButton">edit </button>
          </li>
      )}
    </pre>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are attempting to do this with DOM manipulation (not a page refresh)?

Comment: Hi, best would be to store your data in the order you want to display it in. Can you post your entire component code? A [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) snippet. Also try to be as clear and specific as possible in what your expected result should be. By on top, do you mean above the previous list entries?

Comment: What if you include the methods , items.slice(0).reverse().map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just change this code

```
 <pre>
      {datas.map((data, i) =>
          <li reverse key={i} className="myList">
            {data.input}
            <button onClick={()=>this.fRemove(i)} className="myListButton">remove </button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.fEdit(i)} className="myListButton">edit </button>
          </li>
      )}
    </pre>
```

### To this

```
 <pre className="reverse-list">
      {datas.map((data, i) =>
          <li key={i} className="myList">
            {data.input}
            <button onClick={()=>this.fRemove(i)} className="myListButton">remove </button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.fEdit(i)} className="myListButton">edit </button>
          </li>
      )}
    </pre>
```

## CSS

```
.reverse-list{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

#### Note: reverse property only works on Ordered-list ol tag and the reversed attribute of the ol tag is not supported in Edge prior version 79.